# HTML Input Text select() method not working with Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

**ISSUE:**

I have legacy code that runs with IE that I am trying to make cross-browser compatible. One of the features I have been struggling to get working on  modern browsers (Chrome in particular) is the .select() function on Input Text. Currently users enter in a value into a field, and then hit the "find on page" button, and the relevant text will be highlighted in the table below.

Internet Explorer:

[image: Working select() functionality in IE]

Google Chrome:

[image: Broken select() in Chrome]

As you can see above, in Chrome, the text is not highlighted. Leading me to believe that the select() functionality is **NOT** supported in Chrome. However, according to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_text_select.asp this function is supported by Chrome.

**RELEVANT CODE:**

HTML Button for text selection:

```
<td align="center"><input type="text" name="textSearchInput" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {textSearch(textSearchInput.value); return false;}" size="15" maxlength="30"><button type="button" id="formSubmit2" onclick="textSearch(textSearchInput.value);"><bean:message key="fp.inventory.textSearch"/></button></td>
```

JavaScript for searching and highlighting that **WORKS** in Internet Explorer but **DOES NOT** work in Chrome:

```
      var oRange = null;

      function textSearch(str)
      {
        if ((str == null) || (str == ''))
          return;

        if (oRange == null)
        { // first entry, or wrap search from the end
          oRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        }
        else
        { // move caret forward
          oRange.move('character', 1);
        }
        var found = oRange.findText(str);
        if (found)
        { // highlight and scroll to there
          oRange.focus();
          oRange.select();
          oRange.scrollIntoView(false);
        }
        else
        { // see if str exists at all by going backward
          found = oRange.findText(str, -1);
          if (found)
          { // wrap search
            oRange = null;
            textSearch(str);
          }
        }
```

Is there anything else that I am missing from this? I am not the most well-versed in either HTML or JavaScript so I could be missing something basic..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

createTextRange is not supported in Chrome

http://help.dottoro.com/ljouisvm.php

You'll need to detect the browser and use an alternative.

This may work:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange